# Calculating a contour integral with a square root

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

Define $f$ by $$f(z) = \frac{z^{1/2}}{z^2+z+1}$$ where $z \mapsto z^{1/2}$ is the holomorphic function on $\mathbb{C} \setminus (-\infty,0] $ and $z^{1/2}$ is the regular square root for real $z>0$.

Compute the integral $$\int^{\infty}_0\frac{x^{1/2}}{x^2+x+1}dx.$$

I thought of computing the residues of $f$ and then doing a contour integration over the upper half circle going from $\theta = 0$ to $\theta = 3\pi/4$. But in my calculations I always get stuck. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: The standard method that works for $f_a(z)=\frac{z^a}{z^2+z+1}$ for any $a\in (-1,1)$ is to use the closed contour $C:0\to \infty \to i\infty\to -\infty\to -i\infty \to \infty \to 0$, continuing $f_a$ analytically along the contour, so that on the $(\infty,0)$ piece at the end we have $e^{2i\pi a} f_a(z)$ instead of the original $f_a(z)$. Then $\int_C f_a(z)dz$ is found with the residue theorem.

Comment: @reuns same comment as below; is there no problem with the negative real axis and the square root?

Comment: The key is **continuing $f_a$ analytically along the contour**. You have then to choose the right function to apply the residue theorem, namely the right branch of $f_a$ meromorphic on $\Bbb{C}-[0,\infty)$.

Comment: @reuns would that eventually lead to the same result as posted below?

Comment: @reuns in your first comment, if I apply it to my situation, something seems to go wrong as $a=1/2$ and thus the $(\infty,0)$ piece will become $e^{i\pi}f_a(z) = -f_a(z)$, cancelling out with the other one....

Comment: It doesn't cancel as we integrate in opposite direction. It fails (cancels) at $a=0$ sorry I forgot this case.

Comment: @reuns ah okay, that wasn't really clear to me. So we get $2\int f_a(x)dx = 2\pi i \text{res}_{z_0}$ ?

Comment: $2 \int_0^\infty f_{1/2}(x)dx =\int_C f_{1/2}(z)dz= 2i\pi \sum Res(...)$

Comment: @reuns sure,  but in this case we only have one pole in the contour no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do the substitution $x=y^2$ and $\mathrm dx=2y\,\mathrm dy$, your integral becomes$$\int_0^\infty\frac{2y^2}{y^4+y^2+1}\,\mathrm dy=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{y^2}{y^4+y^2+1}\,\mathrm dy$$The roots of $y^4+y^2+1$ are $\pm\frac12\pm\frac{\sqrt3}2i$. Among these, those with imaginary part greater than $0$ are $\pm\frac12+\frac{\sqrt3}2i$. So, by the residue theorem,\begin{align}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{y^2}{y^4+y^2+1}\,\mathrm dy&=2\pi i\left(\operatorname{res}_{z=\frac12+\frac{\sqrt3}2i}\frac{z^2}{z^4+z^2+1}+\operatorname{res}_{z=-\frac12+\frac{\sqrt3}2i}\frac{z^2}{z^4+z^2+1}\right)\\&=2\pi i\left(\frac{\sqrt3-i}{4\sqrt3}-\frac{\sqrt3+i}{4\sqrt3}\right)\\&=\frac\pi{\sqrt3}.\end{align}

Comment: yes but do we have to integrate along the path that I mentioned or not?

Comment: I also got stuck computing the contour going from $R e^{i3 \pi / 4}$ to $0$

Comment: In order to prove that the equality$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{y^2}{y^4+y^2+1}\,\mathrm dy=2\pi i\left(\operatorname{res}_{z=\frac12+\frac{\sqrt3}2i}\frac{z^2}{z^4+z^2+1}+\operatorname{res}_{z=-\frac12+\frac{\sqrt3}2i}\frac{z^2}{z^4+z^2+1}\right)$$holds, one must integrate $f$ from $-R$ up to $R$ and then along a half-circle in $\{z\in\Bbb C\mid\operatorname{Im}z\geqslant0\}$ from $R$ back to $-R$.

Comment: but isn't the square root undefined on the negative real axis as stated in the problem?

Comment: Have I mentioned the square root of a negative real number in my answer?

Comment: no but your contour integration goes through the negative real axis

Comment: Yes, but then the function that I am integrating is $\frac{z^2}{z^4+z^2+1}$. Do you see a square root in the expression?

Comment: Ah true! I've never done contour integrals with substitutions, so that's why I was thrown off. thanks!